# How to fix error code 1415 in MySql workbench when I want to create a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got the following error when I try to run my sql code: Error Code: 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function
I am trying to create a trigger.

```
USE `mydb`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Shops_AFTER_INSERT` $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`Shops_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Shops` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE threshold INT;
SET threshold = 50;
IF (Shops.number_of_sales>threshold) THEN
    SELECT concat('We are running out of ', Shops.item_name, 'Please refill stock on')
    FROM Shops;
        END IF;
```

END$$

Comment: You have a `SELECT` in this trigger, but you are not using [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) or [SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) to save the result to a variable. What did you intend for the destination of the result of the `SELECT`?

Comment: I am trying to display a message when the trigger is activated

Comment: That's not what triggers are for. They can't return result sets or display anything.